# ssh No such file or directory

Tags: node.js, ssh, ssh-keys, windows-shell, github-for-windows

I had to wipe out my Windows OS. I went to check if I had ab **ssh** still and there was none so I created one.
Went through the proper steps and even got the agent ID. 
Now when I try and find the `id/rsa/pub` using **bash** it tells me no file or directory.
But I can find that ssh file using my **file explorer**.
Trying to get **ssh** keys to reload up to my **GitHub** and **Heroku**.

After searching **stackoverflow** I did find an article saying to run the command `env|grep HOME` and make sure `HOMEDRIVE=C:` was set to `HOMEDRIVE=C:Users/Samson/` but mine is not. 
If that is the correct fix how do i set `HOMEDRIVE=C:` = to `Users/Samson/`
I am on a **Windows Machine**
If that isn't the correct fix, I'm open to suggestions. I am extrememly green to this. 
[image]
[image]

Comment: Please edit the question to explain how to attempt to connect to github and heroku, and what is the error message displayed when trying to do this.

Comment: Based on the screenshots, it seems that the SSH keys are correct. The bash commands have incorrect syntaxes or paths, which explains why bash returns errors: the first command - as explained by bash - tries to run a program called `sltdev@protonmail.com`, which does not exist.

Comment: I have not tried to connect to github and heroku. I successfully did this before prior to having to reinstall windows on my machine. After I reloaded windows i created another SSH and wanted to print out the public key so I can copy and paste it inside of the github ssh settings inside of my github profile.

Comment: The third bash command in the screenshot tries to execute a public key file, and gets the path wrong: `id_rsa/pub` instead of `id_rsa.pub`.

Comment: Please add the output of `ssh -v ...` (where "..." are additional parameters).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Problem

There are two problems in the attempt to display the ssh public key, shown in the screenshot:

- No command is used, the file path is entered directly. The command [`cat`](http://www.linfo.org/cat.html) may be used for this purpose.
- The file path is incorrect: `id_rsa/pub` instead of `id_rsa.pub`.

### Solution

In order to view the public key file content, try the following command in bash:

```
cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

Otherwise, you may simply open the file from windows explorer, using a text editor (e.g. notepad).

Answer (score 1):

You have to generate key first
Use this command to generate key
**ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "youremail@example.com"**
Enter the above email which you have in you github.
And now press enter and then you key will generate, and you will be able to acquire you ssh key
This command --
**ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "youremail@example.com"**

Answer (score 0):

> I am on a Windows Machine

Its okay to be on a Windows machine, but you should run these commands from a Git Bash window and not a windows command prompt or an anaconda command prompt. That maybe your real problem.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).